# A problem from Isaacs's Finite Group Theory

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory, p-groups

I was revisiting group theory in detail and reading Isaacs's Finite Group Theory book in my own time. Sorry that I am asking an exercise question but this is the one I am stuck completely. Any help will be really appreciated.

The problem is **1F.3 on page 40.**

> Let $G=NP$ be a finite group, where $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, and $P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ with $N\cap P=1$, and assume that the conjugation action of $P$ on $N$ is faithful. Show that $P$ acts faithfully on at least one orbit of this action.

The given hint is that we have to consider $x\in N$ with the properly that $P\cap P^x$ is least in size and then to show that $P$ acts faithfully on the $P$-orbit containing $x$. My guess is that somehow we have to use Theorem 1.38 of the book but I can not figure out how. I have given Theorem 1.38 below; here $O_p(G)$ stands for the $p$-core of $G$ that is the unique largest normal $p$-subgroup of $G$, and it can be found by taking the intersection of all of the Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your conditions imply that $O_p(G)=1$. Does that help you?

Comment: It's Isaacs, not Issacs.

Comment: @DerekHolt Sorry, my bad. I have corrected

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Thanks. Can you please give a little more hint on how p-Core is trivial here?

Comment: $O_p(G)$ centralizes $N$, but we are told that $P$ acts faithfully on $N$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks. This I understand. Now when p-Core is trivial how I should use Theorem 1.38?

Comment: Well, suppose that $P$ doesn't act faithfully on the $P$-orbit contains $x$, so there's a kernel $Q$. What can you say about $Q$?

Comment: It's clear that $Q$ is normal in $P$, and slightly more difficult to prove that it is normal in $P^x$, but the problems in Isaacs' book are often challenging!

Comment: @DerekHolt  Thanks for your help. I can understand $Q$ is normal in $P$ as it is kernel. I think I understood why Q is a subgroup of P. In order to prove $Q$ is normal in $P$, I was stuck in one place. I need to show if $n\in N$ is in the orbit that contains $x$ then $n^{g^x}$ is also in the same orbit for all $g\in P$. Is it at all true? If so any help please?

Comment: @ David A. Craven Thanks. Along with Derek's comment, I guess if we can show that $Q$ is normal in $P$ then it should be enough (By Th. 1.38 as in the post) since $O_p(G)$ is trivial. I just want to confirm that it is enough to run all $x$ in $N$ so that $\{P^x|x\in N\}$ is actually the set of Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$. Is this is the case beacuse of $G=NP$ and $N\cap P$ is trivial?

Comment: $Q$ is the kernel of the action of $P$ on the $P$-orbit that contains $x$, so of course $Q$ is a normal subgroup of $P$ - that is easy! The tricky part of this question  is to prove that $Q$ is also normal in $P^x$, and you do not seem to have addressed that yet. You need to prove that in order to apply Thm 1.38.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks. I was actually doing that. During the process, I needed to show what I asked in my previous comment. That is if $n\in N$ is in the orbit that contains $x$ then does $n^{g^x}$ is also in the same orbit for all $g\in P$? Sorry if I am missing something bluntly. My sincere apologies.

Comment: I don't see why $n^{g^x}$ should be in that orbit. As a hint, note that $xQx^{-1} \le P$, so $xqx^{-1}q^{-1} \in P$ for all $q \in Q$ but we  also have $xqx^{-1}q^{-1} \in N$, and $P \cap N=1$, so $x$ centralizes $Q$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is time to answer this question!

As has been pointed out in comments, we have $[O_p(G),N] \le N \cap O_p(G) = 1$ and $O_p(G) \le P$ so, since we are told that $P$ acts faithfully by conjugation on $N$, we must have $O_p(G)=1$.

Following the hint, choose $x \in N$ such that $|P \cap P^x|$ is minimal, and let $Q$ be the kernel of the action of $P$ on the orbit of $P$ on $N$ that contains $x$. So $Q \le P \cap P^x$ and clearly $Q \unlhd P$.

If we could prove that $Q \unlhd P^x$ then since we know from Theorem 1.38 of Isaacs that $O_p(G)$ is the largest subgroup of $P \cap P^x$ that is normal in both $P$ and $P^x$, we would have $Q \le O_p(G) =1$, so $P$ acts faithfully on this orbit, adn we are done.

So it remains to prove that $Q \unlhd P^x$ (which I found the most challenging part of this question).

Now $Q \le P^x \Rightarrow xQx^{-1} \le P$ so, for all $q \in Q$, we have $xqx^{-1}q^{-1} \le P$. But, since $N$ is normal in $G$, we also have $xqx^{-1}q^{-1} \le N$, so $xqx^{-1}q^{-1}=1$, and $x$ centralizes $Q$.

So $Q \unlhd P \Rightarrow Q = Q^x \unlhd P^x$, and we are done.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sorry I got late to address your comments. My sincere thanks to you for the detailed answer. It clarifies everything. Thanks a lot. I enjoyed the problem along the way.